# Save Data to File via Ajax POST and PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I just want to save some JSON (generated with Javascript) in a file on the server. 
But I even don't get it to work with a simple string:

HTML File:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
#test{
padding:20px 50px;
background:#ccc;
color:#000;
}
</style>
<script>
$(function(){
$('#test').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "page.php",
        data: {"foo": "bar"},
        processData: false,
        contentType: 'application/json'
    });

});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="test">
KLICK
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And the php file is something like this:

```
<?php
$myFile = "testFile.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w');
fwrite($fh,$_POST['data']);
fwrite($fh,$_POST['foo']);
fwrite($fh,$_POST["foo"]);
fwrite($fh,$_POST[foo]);
fclose($fh);
```

Nothing worked. I also tried

```
$.ajax({
    var datatosend="foo bar";
    url: "page.php",
    data: datatosend,
    processData: false
    });
```

I don't know what could be wrong. The txt file is there after clicking the div in the html file. But there is no content in the file. If I just write $_POST to the text file, the file contains the Text "Array", meaning that $_POST has some content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few things could be going wrong here.  Check the permissions on the directory your are trying to write to. Also make sure that your ajax call is using the POST method.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "page.php",
  type : 'POST',
  ...
});
```

As sated in the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), the type parameter sets the request type, POST or GET.

> The type of request to make ("POST" or "GET"), default is "GET".

---

Another thing to consider is that you are not actually writing JSON data.  The data is send in that format but when it gets to the `$_POST` variable it has been converted into an array.  What you should try doing is writing a PHP array to the file -

```
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w');
fwrite($fh,'<?php $arr='.var_export($_POST['data'],true).' ?>');
fclose($fh);
```

That should give a file similar to this -

```
<?php
  $arr = array(
    'foo'=>'bar'
  )
?>
```

As you can see, the `var_export()` function returns a parsable version of the variable.

- [`var_export()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php)

> **var_export** — Outputs or returns a parsable string representation of a variable

Comment: I tried also the type "POST" and the code with var_export. Nothing worked for me. The Output with the var_export was <?php $arr=NULL ?>

Comment: Are you sure that `$_POST['data']` contains the actual data?  you might also want to turn on error reporting to see if there are any underlying exceptions...

Comment: I'm note sure ;) What do you mean with error reporting? If I write `error_reporting(E_ALL);` to the php file and just open the php file in the browser it tells me `Notice: Undefined index: data in ...` and so on. But that has to be, because if I directly open the php file $_POST has to be NULL.

Comment: `Undefined index: data` means that the JSON is not being sent in that variable.  Try `print_r($_POST)` and see what you get...

Comment: I tried `fwrite($fh,print_r($_POST,true));` . Then the output in the text file is `Array()` ... an empty Array. That means the Ajax request doesn't send any data, right? But why not?

Comment: I didn't mean place the contents of `print_r` in the file - just to look at it to see whats inside... Make sure that your javascript is sending data...  Try looking at the variable before sending it through ajax...

Comment: "Try looking at the variable before sending it thorugh ajax" ... how can I do this? It's just a simple string: `data: "foo bar"`. I can't see any reason why it won't be be send.
Edit: When I just print_r() at the top of the php file the output is again an empty array.

Comment: which means the data is not being sent... you'll have to do some debugging on your js code...

Comment: Ok, I think I've got the solution :)
Removing     
   `processData: false,
    contentType: 'application/json'`
and changing `data: {"foo": "bar"}` to `data: {foo: "bar"}` seems to work. Now $_POST is an array with `[foo] => bar` . Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a `POST` call, see below:

```
$('#test').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "page.php",
        type : 'post', 
        data: {"foo": "bar"},
        processData: false,
        contentType: 'application/json'
    });

});
```

Comment: Oh yeah, I forgot that in the example above. But that also doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

By default, all $.ajax() requests are sent using the GET method, not POST. You'll need to specify the type as 'POST':

```
$.ajax({
    var datatosend="foo bar";
    url: "page.php",
    type: 'post',
    data: datatosend,
    processData: false
    });
```

From the documentation:

> type - String
>
> Default: 'GET'
>
> The type of request to make ("POST" or "GET"), default is "GET". Note:
>   Other HTTP request methods, such as PUT and DELETE, can also be used
>   here, but they are not supported by all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

May be it should be

```
    $.ajax({
    url: "page.php",
    type: "POST", // add this
    data: {"foo": "bar"},
    processData: false,
    contentType: 'application/json'
});
```

**OR**

in PHP use `$_REQUEST` instead of `$_POST`